# How to create a docker container which every night make a backup of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

Hello i have created mysql image and with this command

```
docker run --name db-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest  --> Run container with my sql
```

docker pull mysql --> create image with mysql

```
docker run --name db_mysql-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mami -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
```

i execute it but after that i don't know what to do and how to make a DB in this container and the job for the backup

If someone can help me with step by step what to do

Comment: How do you want to backup? First and foremost, I would strongly recommend that you mount MySQL's data directory to avoid data loss if the container is destroyed. The easiest backup solution would be to run `mysqldump` in a Cron job on the host machine.

Comment: can you show me how to make this cron job,with example

Comment: The MySQL documentation has [a whole section on backup and recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html).  Figure out how to do that without Docker; many of the paths can run just fine from the host (or another host) pointing at a containerized MySQL.  Once you've worked out how to back things up, if you think it's appropriate to run it in a container, _then_ try to package it up.  This isn't a task that specifically requires Docker, though.

Comment: follow the documentation for the official docker mysql image : https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql#creating-database-dumps

Answer (score 5):

You could use the cron service from your host system to run the following command as described in the [documentation for the mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql#creating-database-dumps):

crontab example for running the command every night at 2:00 am:

```
00 02 * * * /usr/bin/docker exec db-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"my-secret-pw"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

---

Alternatively you could run another container designed just for this task such as [deitch/mysql-backup](https://hub.docker.com/r/deitch/mysql-backup):

```sh
docker run --name db-mysql -d \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw \
    -e MYSQL_USER=my-user \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-user-password \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my-db \
    mysql:latest

docker run -d --restart=always \
    --name=db-backup \
    -e DB_DUMP_BEGIN=0200 \
    -e DB_SERVER=db-mysql \
    -e DB_USER=my-user \
    -e DB_PASS=my-user-password \
    -e DB_NAMES=my-db \
    -e DB_DUMP_TARGET=/db \
    -v /somewhere/on/your/host/:/db \
    databack/mysql-backup
```

You also need to make sure the `/somewhere/on/your/host/` folder is writable by users of group `1005`:

```sh
sudo chgrp 1005 /somewhere/on/your/host/
sudo chmod g+rwX /somewhere/on/your/host/
```

But this container must have a mean to connect to your `db-mysql` container. For that you create a docker network and connect both containers to it:

```sh
docker network create mysql-backup-net
docker network connect mysql-backup-net db-backup
docker network connect mysql-backup-net db-mysql
```